# How to hide link by guard angular2

Tags: angular2-routing

How to hide admin link in view html. I have to guard :Admin and Manager

Router config :

```
{
   path: 'manager',
   component: ManagerComponent,
   canActivate: [ManagerGuard]
},
{
   path: 'user',
   component: UserAdminComponent,
   canActivate: [AdminGuard]
}
```

In view :

```
 <li>
    <a routerLink="/user" routerLinkActive="active-link">User</a>
 </li>
```

I want to hide link on /user for ManagerGuard when but show for AdminGuard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Also if already answered in a way which might be helpful, I used here another approach. As you already have your canActivate method in the Guard, you could also inject your navigation component with that Guards and you can call these canActivate methods directly:

In your component which holds the navigation

```
constructor(private adminGuard: AdminGuard)
```

and then in the template

```
<li *ngIf="adminGuard.canActivate()">
  <a routerLink="/user" routerLinkActive="active-link">User</a>
</li>
```

**Edit**

This does not work in prod mode in my case (if you use parameters which have to be injected). I just tried to compile it but angular complains about the missing parameters. If you do not use parameters, this works fine, or, if you do not use the parameters in your function - then simply pass

```
<li *ngIf="adminGuard.canActivate(null,null)">
  <a routerLink="/user" routerLinkActive="active-link">User</a>
</li>
```

Another thing: If you is variables like the 'adminGuard' above in the template, it must be public - not private.

Comment: This is a great solution. What if your canActivate method uses parameters? e.g. canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot). How do you get the specified route params into the template?

Comment: I just stumbled myself over that one. If you trying to build your app in prod mode, it complains about those missing parameters. I will check if it's possible anyway to achieve this goal.

Comment: I ended up writing my own custom directive that basically replaces your *ngIf. As I use the parameters, I'm not able to call it directly - so I have to duplicate the logic everywhere I need to apply permissions e.g. *showForRoles="[UserTypes.Admin, UserTypes.SuperUser]"

Comment: Feature request here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25342

I think a lot of people bake in redirects in to guards which would cause things to not work as expected. The solution here is correct, but additional arguments can be added to the guard (like I show in the feature request) to allow it to work with redirect or not.

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion this has nothing to do with the router itself.

Your Guards may call another service which has the information about which kind of user is logged in: Admin or Manager.

You should create a service that knows the type of the user. Then inject this service with [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) into your component where you have the `routerLink`.

There you can ask the service and toggle the link with `*ngIf`:

```
<li *ngIf="myService.getCurrentUser().isAdmin()">
    <a routerLink="/user" routerLinkActive="active-link">User</a>
</li>
```

So the service provides a function that gives you the user which is currently logged in and the `isAdmin()`-function of the user returns `true` or `false`. If the user is admin then the `<li>` will be shown, otherwise it will be hidden.

This is just an example but I hope you get the point. It has more to do with basic functionality of Angular 2 rather than the router of Angular 2. More information about `*ngIf` can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html).

Comment: I agree that it makes sense to use the logic inside your service instead of Guard. Guard is supposed to protect component from not authorised access. It may include some other functionalities like navigating to access denied page.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense then for the guard to use the service as well, since you don't want to have two places in your code determining if the user has access to that route?