# How show only links to modules that I can active in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

I use router and guards with CanActivate. It works fine, but I need show only in my menu the "activable" links.

Has router any option as "isActivable"?

Example:

```
<ul>
 <li routerLink="home" routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="isActivable">Home</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507064/how-to-hide-link-by-guard-angular2

Comment: But these solution add a lot of boilerplate, I need add the guard in the menu and in the routing module...

Answer (score 0):

You can just inject your Guard in the constructor of your Component.
Like this:

```
constructor(private yourGuard: YourGuard){}
```

And int the Template:

```
<ul>
 <li routerLink="home" routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="yourGuard.canActivate()">Home</li>
<ul>
```

Of course you have to specify your guard in the Router...